# Microsoft Graph - how to move a mail to a public folder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Microsoft Graph API [provides a method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to move a mail message to a different folder:

```
POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}/move
```

This works fine when moving a mail message around local folders, but returns a 404 when moving a mail message to or from a Public folder.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
    "message": "The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the correct properties.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "53cf2d12-b551-4fa5-97c4-0d70c99013ec",
      "date": "2020-04-03T16:20:08"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the mail message is moved successfully.

The documentation is a bit unclear about support for Public folders, but most operations appear to work ok, so I'm not sure if this is something I'm doing wrong, something not supported or a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Public folders are not supported by Microsoft Graph. From https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview#where-is-the-data:

> **Where is the data?**
>
> The Microsoft Graph API supports accessing data in *users' primary
>   mailboxes and in shared mailboxes.* The data can be calendar, mail, or
>   personal contacts stored in a mailbox in the cloud on Exchange Online
>   as part of Office 365, or on Exchange on-premises in a hybrid
>   deployment.
>
> The API does not support accessing in-place archive mailboxes, not on
>   Exchange Online nor on Exchange Server.